# How to tar while excluding a combination of files and directories

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tar

An auction script has the following directory structure

```
/var/www/html/
              file1
              file2

/var/www/html/subdir1/
/var/www/html/subdir2/
/var/www/html/subdir3/
/var/www/html/subdirN/

/var/www/html/uploaded/
                       .htaccess            
                       file3
                       file4

                      /banners/
                               file5
                               file6

                      /cache/
                             file7         <<< exclude
                             file8         <<< exclude

                      /hledmd7phk4u5glq5rks8kb621/        <<< exclude
                                                  file9   <<< exclude
                                                  file10  <<< exclude
                      /ad0hmd7phk4u5glq5rks8kb258/        <<< exclude
                                                  file11  <<< exclude
                                                  file12  <<< exclude
                      /zfddfd7phk4u5glq5rks8kb584/        <<< exclude
                                                  file13  <<< exclude
                                                  file14  <<< exclude
```

A Ubuntu 14.04 tar is being run in crontab -e nightly at present that backs up the entire directory from the /var/www/html/ level using absolute paths. A new tar backup command is needed that will reduce the size of the nightly backup by excluding the combination of files and directories shown above while:

1) including the directory/var/www/html/uploaded/cache/ while excluding
the contents under /var/www/html/uploaded/cache/

2) excluding the long list of ever changing MD5 directory names and
their contents that are created under /var/www/html/uploaded/

Is there a way to do this in one tar command?

Answer (score 0):

Not a final solution for you, but here is a directive way of thinking:

For the first requirement, we can use wildcard like this:

```
tar -cvf test.tgz --exclude=/var/www/html/uploaded/cache/*
```

For the second requirement, MD5 as a filename do not have a string pattern, so more other information should be added to filter those directories.

@ml48603, for how to strcat tar command, here is an example:

```
tar_all_cmd=tar -cvf test.tgz

dir_name="/var/www/html/uploaded/"

ls $dir_name | while read filename; do if [ ${#filename} -ge 8 ]; then $option_head="--exclude=$dir_name"; tar_all_cmd="${tar_all_cmd}${option_head}${filename}"; fi;  done;
```

Comment: 1st: /cache/* is going to grab everything under cache, not just cache, correct? 2nd: The md5 dirs are the only dir names that will be present with a length of 8 characters or greater, as the longest dir name to keep is /banners/ at 7 characters long

Comment: @ml48603 1st, every thing uder cache dir but not cache dir itself; 2nd great insight, more complex shell should meet this requirement then.

Comment: Does tar offer a pattern for directories names greater than a set number of characters?  I haven\t written a shell script before. But it looks like this would be a perfect time to learn how. My Ubuntu server is running /bin/bash shell according to # echo $SHELL

Comment: @ml48603 consider to strcat --exclude option with the dirs. I’m going to add an shell example soon.

Comment: hi @ml48603 FYI, update the answer add an example for strcat the tar command. Feel free for more discussion :)

Comment: @ml48603 please take a little time to help check the updated answer, very appreciated.